# Trying to setup redux history so I can redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to following this react router redux so I can redirect using the push('/') in my components or actions.

Tutorial: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux

I am not sure what I missing but I am getting an error.

The error I am getting in chrome console is:

> bundle.js:3090 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Root`.
>       in Root printWarning @ bundle.js:3090
>
> bundle.js:2684 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> bundle.js:20893 The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in Provider (created by Root)
>       in Root

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import reducers from './reducers';
import Root from './root';

// Create a history of your choosing (we're using a browser history in this case)
const history = createHistory();
let middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)]

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

render(
  <Root store={store} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

root.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/app';

const Root = ({ store, history }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div className="application-container">
      <App>
        <Switch>
        </Switch>
      </App>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default Root;
```

/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import users from './users';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  users,
});

export default reducers;
```

users.js

```
import Constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  users: [],
  fetching: false,
};

const users = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.LOADING_USERS:
      return {...state, fetching: true};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default users;
```

my package.json deps:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jest": "^22.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.10.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Is the App component imported correctly??

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes, this was all working fine before I tried to setup the history with the ConnectedRouter.

Comment: Whats in the "./users" file?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ConnectedSwitch` here? Like in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples/BasicExample.js

Comment: @Chaitanya I updated my question with that users file.  It is just a reducer.

Comment: @Blankman, I have reproduce your code with react 16.2 and es6. Are you sure all import correct? include history? did you `npm install react-redux react-router-redux redux react-router react-router-dom  redux-thunk history` ?

Comment: make sure you're using version `^5.0.0-alpha.8` and not `4.x.x`, you can install it with `npm install --save react-router-redux@next`

Comment: @hendrathings I added my package.json dep in the question so you can see what I have.

Comment: @Blankman, Yeps that is the problem. just update `react-router-redux` with version 5. it will solve your problem

Comment: Does your Root component not need a render function?

Answer (score 11):

This could be an issue with dependency mismatch. The repository also mentions something regarding this:

> This (react-router-redux 5.x) is the version of react-router-redux for
>   use with react-router 4.x. Users of react-router 2.x and 3.x want to
>   use react-router-redux found at the legacy repository.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/w03mw1zwy5) is a working codesandbox set with `react-router-redux` 5.x and `react-router` 4.x for the same tutorial.

**Update:** Seems like you're using `react-router-redux` 4.x which might be causing the errors. [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kjo12j9p9) sandbox uses v4.x and throws errors

Comment: @TarunLalwani it doesn't redirect using push inside of my action.

Comment: I also have thunk which the sandbox doesn't, maybe that is causing an issue the way I am wiring it all up.

Comment: If you can set a repo I can take a look

Comment: Your demo is not using 'push' to redirect to another page, confused?

Comment: You may add `store.dispatch(push('/about'))` and it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing a server side rendering then use BrowserRouter instead in your root.js (See above). This is inside package react-router-dom.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

I would use ConnectedRouter (from react-router-redux) in root.js file only when I am doing serverside rendering. In this case when Hydrate happens (in index.js) in will not throw errors and warnings.

OR 
Please try this. Correct your routing with a ConnectedSwitch as shown in below example:

```
const AppContainer = () => (
      <ConnectedSwitch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<h1>Home <Link to="/about">About</Link></h1>)} />
        <Route path="/about" component={() => (<h1>About <Link to="/">Home</Link></h1>)} />
      </ConnectedSwitch>
    )

const App = connect(state => ({
  location: state.location,
}))(AppContainer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

I am open for discussion. Regards.